# как присвоить время

Tags: c#

Как присвоить время?

Пытался так, но не получилось:

```
     DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(10: 00: 00);
```

Нужно `thisDate1` присвоить значение - 10 часов :00 минут :00 секунд.

Comment: ...какого дня?​

Comment: просто время без даты

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите на возможные перегрузки на сайте [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1), например:

```
DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(год, месяц, день, 10, 0, 0);
```

т.е.

```
DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(год, месяц, день, час, минута, секунда);
```

Либо можете сделать так:

```
DateTime thisDate1 = DateTime.Today;
thisDate1 = thisDate1.AddHours(10);
```

Comment: чисто теоретически можно но у меня программа не подходит под такое решение

Comment: блин не подошла там дата вместе со временем а надо только время

Comment: @ильявитюк Дак вы ведь можете просто игнорировать дату, а вытягивать часы, минуты и секунды из `thisDate1` через соответствующие свойства (`Hour`, `Minute`, `Second`), т.е. например так: `thisDate1.Hour` или вам так не подойдет?

Answer (score 2):

"Просто время без даты" надо хранить в `TimeSpan`, а не в `DateTime`...

```
var thisTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

нашел`

```
DateTimeOffset thisDate2 = new DateTimeOffset(2011, 6, 10, 15, 24, 16, 
                                          TimeSpan.Zero);
```

и у нас будет присвоено значение 15:24:16 в thisDate2

```
15:24:16 +00:00
```

Comment: Помедте свой ответ "галочкой", т.е. как решение, чтобы вопрос не отображался в списке неотвеченных.

Comment: Вы сможете принять свой ответ через 2 дня

Comment: так что помечу ваш ответ :)

Comment: Я там в ответ еще один вариантик подкинул, вдруг окажется удобнее. И, честно говоря, я не знал на счет правила про 2 дня :)

Comment: спасибо попробую вдруг удобней будет

Comment: я раздобыл это здесь https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: полезный сайт!!

Comment: Ну, логично, это же сайт официальной документации _microsoft'а_, а _C#_ - это их продукт (можно сказать сделали свои плюсы с _блэеджеком и плюхами_) :)

Comment: дам ничего не скажешь

Comment: ну ладно все равно спасибо